# Not able to align the html elements

Tags: html, css

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "source.css">
    <title>Blog Master</title>
</head>
<body>  
<div id="login">
    <p id="already_member">Already a member?</p>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="email id">   
</div>      
<div id="heading">
    <h1>Welcome to the world of blogging</h1>
</div>
<p id ="para_part1">Right Here..Write Now</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#login{
    background-color:#e0ded8;
    width:1500px;
    height:30px;
    margin-top:0px;
}

#already_member{
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-style:bold;
    color:white;
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align:top;
}

body{
    background-color:#FAEBD7;
}

#heading{
    background-color:pink;
    text-align:center;border:0.2em solid black;
    -webkit-animation-name: example; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-direction:reverse;  
    margin-top:20px;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes example {
    from {background-color: red;}
    to {background-color: yellow;}
}

#para_part1{
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-style:italic;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
}
```

I'm unable to align the `input` element with the `<p>` tag, 
both are in  same `div`. Please can anyone provide me some help. If you go through the code and run it you will understand what I'm trying to say. Please, can anyone tell me why it is happening or why I am not getting the desired result? Thank You!

Comment: wow it worked..thanks a lot...but can u explain it some bit..whats wrong with my code..

Comment: Your p.#already_member has display: block by default so it occupy the whole line, that is why your input is positioned below, when you set display: inline-block or inline the p only occupy the necessary space to display its contents

Comment: Okay got it..now its really makes sense..:)

Answer (score 2):

Add `float:left;` to your id `already_member`:

```
#already_member{
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-style:bold;
    color:white;
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align:top;
    float:left;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cn3yfn9p/1/)**

Alternatively, you could use `display:inline;` instead of `float:left;`.

```
#already_member{
    font-family:tahoma;
    font-style:bold;
    color:white;
    margin-top:0px;
    text-align:top;
    display:inline;
}
```

**[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/cn3yfn9p/2/)**

Comment: Thanks dude your code also output the same result..please explain it some bit..please can you point out my mistake.

Comment: Glad it helped :) HTML elements will not float for themselves. They will always be below each other, except you float them. You have 2 elements (1 `<p>` tag and 1 `<input />` tag) so you have to float them if you want them to be next to each other. Have a look at the CSS `float` property: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Comment: And have a look at display property as well :) http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Thanks dude..it really helped a lot..thanks for the helping hand..sure i ll go through it and read out the mentioned property in the website.Your description gives the brief idea about it.